# How do I return a nested object with the largest key:value using lodash?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

My object looks like this:

```
players: {
  p1: {
    name: joe,
    points: 25
  },
  p2: {
    name: frank,
    points: 35
  },
  p3: {
    name: tim,
    points: 55
  }
}
```

How would I return the player object with the highest "points" value? For example:

```
{ name: tim, points: 55 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var data = {
  players: {
    p1: {
      name: 'joe',
      points: 25
    },
    p2: {
      name: ' frank',
      points: 35
    },
    p3: {
      name: 'tim',
      points: 55
    }
  }
};

var res = data.players[
  // get all property names
  Object.keys(data.players)
  // get the property name which holds the hghest point
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    // compare and get the property which holds the highest
    return data.players[a].points < data.players[b].points ? b : a;
  })
];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `_.maxBy`

```
_.chain(players)
     .values()
     .maxBy('points')
     .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {p1: {name: 'hello', points: 1}, p2: {name: 'world', points: 2}}
const dataList = _.values(data)
const maxPointItem = dataList.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.points < curr.points ? curr : prev), dataList[0])
```